# Python Selenium Headless Chromedriver taking all white screenshots and can't locate any element?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

Im setting a script up to flush the cache of a certain application, When running chromedriver not headless all xpath locators work fine. I set up the chrome options

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1920,1080")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=chrome_options)

driver.get('link here')

driver.save_screenshot('file.png')
```

link here represents the certain link I will be going to flush the cache.

When running headless I get an unable to locate element error and the screenshots will come back as a blank page. The complete opposite when chrome is not run headless. I'm at a roadblock right now, any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

I've tried setting the windows size as well as changing the path of the chromedriver.

Comment: Can you please provide your link here or DOM?

Comment: @Rock Link is an internal company secure site pretty sure it's not open to the open web, the element its not locating is driver.find_element_by_link_text("DefaultTFNProductList").click() but I've tried commenting that one out and it would find any element provided, not xpath, class name, id anything.

Comment: Please check if element is in iFrame?

Comment: Try maximizing browser to locate elements.

Comment: Which version of chrome and ChromeDriver are you using?